# How do I customize duration of video playback in HTML 5?

Tags: html5-video

I’m working with HTML 5 video. I need to customize the start and end time. I used this code to start playing the video at 60 seconds and end at 70 (duration = 10), but it doesn’t work.

```
<div class="playbox">
<div class="player" id="player3">
<video width="640" height="360" controls><source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4#t=60,10" type="video/mp4"></video>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what do you mean? What happened, and what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

The second number is the end time, not the duration. Your URL should look like this:

http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4#t=60,70

The other problem is that this clip is only 60 seconds long. So try this:
http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4#t=20,30